# R: Within a dataframe filled with various lengths of NA values, add column 2 of each rows to the last column of the row which is not NA

Tags: r

I have a dataframe,filled with numbers and some NA. What I want to do is to add column 2 of each row of the dataframe to the last non-NA column of that row, then delete column 2. So I guess the trick here is to identify and select the last non-NA column of each row, when each row has different number of NAs.

Sample Data:

```
s1 <- c(1,2,1,2,4,NA,NA,NA)
s2 <- c(2,3,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
s3 <-c(3,2,1,4,5,1,NA,NA)
df3 <- rbind(s1,s2,s3)
print(s1)
colnames(df3) <- c("ID","Cash", "V0","V1","V2","V3","V4","V5")
print(df3)
```

```
> print(df3)
   ID Cash V0 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
s1  1    2  1  2  4 NA NA NA
s2  2    3  4 NA NA NA NA NA
s3  3    2  1  4  5  1 NA NA
```

So, the intended operation to the sample dataset above is to add the "Cash" column to the last non-NA column of each row, namely column V2, aka "4" for row 1; column V0, aka "4" for row 2; column "V3", aka "1" for row 3.

After the operation, the desired output should be:

```
s4 <- c(1,1,2,6,NA,NA,NA)
s5 <- c(2,7,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
s6 <-c(3,1,4,5,3,NA,NA)
df4 <- rbind(s4,s5,s6)
colnames(df4) <- c("ID","V0","V1","V2","V3","V4","V5")
print(df4)
```

```
> print(df4)
   ID V0 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
s4  1  1  2  6 NA NA NA
s5  2  7 NA NA NA NA NA
s6  3  1  4  5  3 NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorized option with `max.col`, where we extract the element in each row which is the last non-NA, add with the 'Cash' column values and update that column

```
ij <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(df3)), max.col(!is.na(df3[, -(1:2)]), "last"))
df3[,-(1:2)][ij] <- df3[,-(1:2)][ij] + df3[, "Cash"]
df3[, -2]
#   ID V0 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#s1  1  1  2  6 NA NA NA
#s2  2  7 NA NA NA NA NA
#s3  3  1  4  5  3 NA NA
```